# Not getting a handle of my event object in React

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling

I have an AsyncTypeAhead component in my React code which is basically a dropdown with some values from the server. This component has an onChange method which looks like the following

```
onChange={(s) => handleOnChange(s, evt)}
```

So I am not sure how the value of s is populating but when I debug or console log it is but it doesn't seem to be getting a handle of the evt object. The evt object is always coming back as undefined. Not sure what I need to do to get a handle of the evt object.

Comment: onChange={(s) => handleOnChange(s, evt)}  --> where do i get this `evt` ? If you are using the native `input` then `s` is your event object . You can do this `onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(event)}`

Comment: I am using the native input under the hood. In my variable s, I see an array of objects with length 0 with the object of the item selected, but I am not seeing event anywhere.

Comment: Can you add the code for your input component ??